# How to properly name service files and folders in a monolith codebase?

Tags: python, service, directory, naming-conventions, modularity

I would like to hear your thoughts about naming files and folders in a codebase.
let’s suppose we define different vendor services (paypalService, stripeService etc) and a refund service under payments scope.
Consider the following structure in payments directories:

```
monolith
|
└--payment
     │   __init__.py
     │   views.py
     │   tasks.py
     └───services
     │   │   __init__.py
     │   └───refund
     │       │   __init__.py
     │       │   main.py
     │       │   utils.py
     │   └───vendors
     │       │   __init__.py
     │       └─── stripe
     │          │   __init__.py
     │          │   main.py
     │          │   utils.py
     │       └─── paypal
     │          │   __init__.py
     │          │   main.py
     │          │   utils.py
     │       └─── adyen
     │          │   __init__.py
     │          │   main.py
     │          │   utils.py
```

In this structure, file names do not represent anything by itself (such as `main.py`), but when we look at the full name, including folders, e.g. (`monolith/payment/services/refund/main.py`) this main.py name *does* give the idea that given module contains the main part of whatever service directory it’s in. Same idea applies to all files: the full path for each module clearly describes what the module has.

Some people claim that `__init__.py` is an appropriate place to put main module class to, but I made a research about this and couldn't come across such use-case of it. AFAIK possible use case of `__init__.py` is to define how the directory is served to outside world as a package, e.g. defining `__all__` inside this file makes sense to me.

I came up with this idea (init, main, utils trio) to structure service directories and I would like to hear what you think. All files having similar names such as main, utils tickles me a bit. Is this a bad practice? What can be alternative ways to structure such service directories?

Assumptions:

- Let's suppose each module should have its own specific utils.
- Service modules are big enough to create a package for them and split them into modules such as "utils", "mixins", "main" etc.

Any source to read best practices about this issue will be much appreciated as well!

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally wrong with such a setup, but there isn't anything particularly great about it either (depending on your editor it could be confusing having 14 `main.py` files open...). If you've already started thinking in this direction, then maybe it is time to ditch your monolithic design instead and make the services independent (and pluggable?) apps?  ps: I would keep the `__init__.py` files lean for the same reason as above (I haven't checked newer versions of Django, but earlier versions kept a _lot_ of code in `__init__.py`)

Comment: hey bjorn, thanks for your effort on this. Having 14 `main.py` files open indeed worries me, but that has been the case for a long time. Our file names are generic all the time, such as `views.py`, `tasks.py`, `models.py` etc. What can be alternative way of naming files? For example, under stripeservice folder, should we rename `main.py` to `stripe_service.py`? wdyt?

Comment: Generic-sounding file names have a tendency to accumulate random baggage over time too, so I'm not a big fan in general. There is some tradition for naming single-task modules the same as their package names (`from .stripe import stripe; stripe.foo(..)`). I'm not saying that is better, and there's something to be said for keeping many small modules that do the same task with different backends, structurally similar.

Comment: naming the main module same as the package name sounds great. for the very least, it's the best-looking solution I have so far :D thank you! your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure provided in the question looks good to me. That's absolutely clear.

Not a problem having a lot of files with similar names (Hello, Django! every package has `__init__.py`, `models.py`, `admin.py`, `tests.py`, `templatetags.py` (or a package with the same name).

That's absolutely normal for a framework like solutions to have a lot of similar named files, it allows you to create some sort of "pluggable system" in case you need it now or in the future.

Modern editors work well with the same-named files in different directories by adding prefixes/postfixes with the parent directory name for the case. My favourite IDE PyCharm has a cool plugin for that case [Tabdir plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5045-tabdir).

I like the structure you have. Any modern framework tries to standardize "applications or plugins folders" and that's normal. That is real programming, not  writings tons of ugly files and import it :)

Comment: installed the plugin and looks great! thanks for providing insight. I appreciate it :)